# How to get multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

- table `request` : content of request data
- table `participant` : content of employee who invited

Table `Request`:

```
ID_Request   emp_no  invited_by
-------------------------------
BTR1370      101240  101240 
BTR1371      100259  101240 
BTR1372      100308  101240 
BTR1373      100626  101240
```

Table `Participant`:

```
ID_Participant ID_Request  participant_no   invited_by 
------------------------------------------------------
1              BTR1370     100259           101240
2              BTR1370     100308           101240
3              BTR1370     100626           101240
```

I want to join those tables, and expect to get this result here:

```
ID_Request  participant_no  invited_by
---------------------------------------
BTR1370     100259          101240
BTR1370     100308          101240
BTR1370     100626          101240
BTR1371     100259          101240
BTR1371     100308          101240
BTR1371     100626          101240
BTR1372     100259          101240
BTR1372     100308          101240
BTR1372     100626          101240
BTR1373     100259          101240
BTR1373     100308          101240
BTR1373     100626          101240
```

How can I join those two tables? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I am very grateful for your help

Comment: I think you are looking for `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I don't think so.
because i have tried and show many result that i am not expected it

but, thanks for your respond

Comment: Why not? How about you explain what you're trying to do in words, not just with vague sample data?

Comment: I have tried for those sample with cross join, and the result show 800 rows.

Comment: The result size of the `cross join` for the given sample will definitively be 12. If it's not a cross product you're looking for then please explain how the result depends on the inputs...

Comment: Instead OF Arguing listen to your senior if they says you something there might be reason Behind it.

Comment: Oh okay i understand. I am sorry, maybe my mistake to declare not clear. but it's give me clear from your solution. Thanks all for your suggestion and response

Answer (score 0):

use cross join

```
select TR.ID_Request,TR.participant_no,TR.invited_by from Table_Request TR cross join Table_Participant TP where TR.invited_by = TP.invited_by
```

Answer (score 0):

Use should use [CROSS JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) just like Gordon linoff says:
You may include a where clause to make it behave like an inner join - Ie. where a.invited_By = b.invited_by

```
    declare @myt1 table (id_request nvarchar(50),emp_no int, invited_by int)
insert into @myt1
values 

('BTR1370',  101240  ,101240), 
('BTR1371',  100259  ,101240), 
('BTR1372',  100308  ,101240), 
('BTR1373',  100626  ,101240)

declare @myt2 table ( id_participant int,id_request nvarchar(50),participant_no int, invited_by int)
insert into @myt2
values

(1  ,'BTR1370',  100259 , 101240 ),
(2  ,'BTR1370',  100308 , 101240 ),
(3  ,'BTR1370',  100626 , 101240 )

select a.id_request,b.participant_no,a.invited_by from @myt1 a
cross join @myt2  b

order by a.id_request
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a CROSS JOIN is not what you are after, and not being able to see more sample data, I can only assume you want an inner join

```
SELECT r.ID_Request, p.participant_no, r.invited_by
FROM Table_Request r
    INNER JOIN Table_Participant p
        ON r.ID_Request = p.ID_Request
```